# Call Javascript function on click of dynamic tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and I have not written a lot of jQuery/JavaScript.  I am trying to call a JavaScript function on click of a nav-tab.  The nav-tabs are added to the page dynamically.  I know the "name" of the specific tab which I need to call the function when clicked, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out where or how to add it.  Below is the code that dynamically adds the tabs to the page:

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs  nav-tabs-line" role="tablist">
        @{
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.Tabs.Tabs.Count(); i++)
            {
                var n = Model.Tabs.Tabs[i];
                <li class="nav-item" style="@(n.isHidden == true ? "display:none;" : "")">
                    <a class="nav-link @(activeAdded == false && n.isHidden == false ? "active" : "")" data-toggle="tab" href="#@n.href" role="tab" aria-selected="true" id="@n.aId" style="@(n.isHidden == true ? "display:none;" : "")">
                        @n.name
                    </a>
                </li>
                if (activeAdded == false && n.isHidden == false)
                {
                    activeAdded = true;
                    tabstr += "$('#" + @n.href + "').addClass('active');$('#" + @n.aId + "').click();";
                }
                if (n.isHidden == true)
                {
                    tabstr += "$('#" + @n.href + "').css('display','none');";
                }
            }
        }
    </ul>
```

I need to call the function `loadRequests()` when the tab named "Support" is clicked. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".nav-item", function() { yourfunction(this) })` (there are other formats but this is the least likely to get wrong when starting out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event delegation on the parent `<ul>`.

```
$('ul.nav').on('click', '.nav-item:contains("Support")', function(e){
    loadRequests();
    //do something else
});
```

```js
$('ul.nav').on('click', '.nav-item:contains("Support")', function(e) {
  console.log('clicked');
  //do something else
});
$('button').click(function(e) {
  $('ul.nav').append(`<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#@n.href" role="tab" aria-selected="true" id="@n.aId">
                        ${Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'something else' : 'Support'}
                    </a>
                </li>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs  nav-tabs-line" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#@n.href" role="tab" aria-selected="true" id="@n.aId">
                        Support
                    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<button>Add Tab</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It works like a charm!

Comment: @RaniRadcliff No problem.